# Which region has the most granular census data?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, census

Which region (ideally, at least city sized) has census data with the finest geographical resolution?

In addition, which region has the most detailed census data (i.e, most dimensions / categories in data)?

Looking for places outside and inside the USA. 
Census-like (crowdsourced?) data is OK too!

Comment: Official US Census data is collected at the "block" level but released only on the "block group" level. The smallest block group would have the highest geographical resolution, but I suspect that's not what you're asking.